# Vue3 js v-bind css tailwind conditionally based on status value

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I have a status property that can change  and I need to change CSS tailwind each time that value changes using v-bind :class on vue3 3 how to achieve so ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
<div :class="{ 'tailwind-class': status }">
```